# Android Asset file not upgraded on app upgrade

Tags: android

In my Android application, I have some configuration for a library in a text file called `library.cfg`. This file lives in `assets\library` in my Android Studio project. (Both the application and library are proprietary, so I can't divulge more details).

I install the app with on our target device (which is running 2.3.4 Gingerbread, if that is relevant). The `library.cfg` file appears correctly.

I edit the `library.cfg` file to include a new setting value.

I then install the app again with the same signing config, but an incremented version name/code. The new APK includes the new settings in the asset file.

If I only install the app, the changes to `library.cfg` are not reflected by the copy of the file at `/data/data/com.myapp.package/library/library.cfg`. The file is the same as in the original install.

If I uninstall the app and then install the second build of the app with the updated config file, `/data/data/com.myapp.package/library/library.cfg` contains the added values.

Why isn't the file updated when I upgrade the app rather than uninstalling/reinstalling? What do I have to do to ensure that the file is updated during upgrade?

Comment: That is what I am saying. Opening the file after app upgrade/startup shows no changes, and the library which uses the file is not changing it's behavior as expected without uninstall/install.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Yes, that seems to have fixed the problem. I wonder how the library is accessing that file. If you write up a quick answer to that effect, I'll accept!

Comment: Done, I post the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file with `Context.getAssets()` on each startup of the app, when upgrade the app, first launch it and after that check if the file has change.

Its seems that until you access the file, it is not extracted from the apk to `/data/data/<your-package>/`

Comment: It would be nice to see some code sample for this answer.