# Overwrite of asset file when upgrading app

Tags: android, file, deployment, updates, c++builder

I'm stucked on a weird problem. 
I have a xml config file in my project to which I added two values. This XML file is stored in `.\assets\internal\` which refers to `data\data\<Application ID>\files` . This file is, as all my other project's files, stated as "Always Replaced" (seen from Project, Deployment).

The thing is when I upgrade a previous version of the app not containing these two new values to the new app, the XML file is not upgraded to the one in the new APK, and leads to bugs in my app.

I've seen some other people with this problem but I get other errors.

> [Android Asset file not upgraded on app upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651788/android-asset-file-not-upgraded-on-app-upgrade?rq=1)

I get `File not found error` by trying to open `SharedActivityContext()->getAssets()->open('config.xml');` though the file is stored in `.\assets\internal\`... (accessed by `IOUtils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath() + PathDelim + "config.xml"` in my code).

I get all the same errors by storing the file in `.\assets\`, which stores it in the external storage + I don't find a way to get a path from TPath to this external storage so I have to write the path in my code.

That said, I have no errors when I fresh install my app by deleting the previous version, but I can't do that to all my devices.

How can I upgrade an asset file (EDIT : with c++ Builder) ? Or should I store it in `res\raw` to get it upgraded at every app upgrade ?

Comment: `stored in .\assets\internal\ which refers to data\data\<Application ID>\files .` No. It does not. Those are not the same if you mean that.

Comment: `...getAssets()->open('config.xml');` That should then be `...getAssets()->open('internal\\config.xml');`

Comment: `How can I upgrade an asset file ? ` Using your development IDE you put a new xml file in the assets folder for that project.

Comment: `get all the same errors by storing the file in .\assets\, which stores it in the external storage`. No that does not happen automatically.

Comment: When you say "This XML file is stored in .\assets\internal\", do you mean that the file is stored in that folder in your Android Studio project on your development machine? Note that the folders in your AS project do not map to any folders on the device where you run your app.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I see that in my IDE (C++Builder), but it is indicated as "Remote Path", so I was supposing that it means "Path from Android".

Comment: @greenapps See loading and deploying files http://docwiki.appmethod.com/appmethod/1.13/topics/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files

Comment: Why are you providing a link.? If you have anything to tell then tell.

Comment: Wait...you are writing an Android app in C++Builder? I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: Write once. Run on Windows, Android and iOS.

Comment: @greenapps Could you tell me something more than a "no" ? How can I know where a `.\assets\internal\` file end up in the android System ?

Comment: I suceeded to read the file as the stackoverflow link mention with 

`_di_JInputStream file = SharedActivityContext()->getAssets()->open(StringToJString("internal\/config.xml"));
  file->read();
  file->close();`
but the file is still not overwritten, I still get an error when trying to read the new values added to the new config file.

Comment: Well you did not tell how you put a new file in assets and what you did further. Come to the point please.

Comment: You are so helpful thank you for your comments ! <3 @greenapps